# PDFBox specify cert in the signature dictionary when using adbe.x509.rsa_sha1

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

When using adbe.x509.rsa_sha1 as subfilter in pdfbox, it's required by the specification (32000-1:2008, page 468) to set the 'Cert' signature dictionary field. There is no method in PDSignature or COSDictionary to set this 'Cert' field, that should contain "an array of byte strings that shall represent the x.509 certificate chain (...)".

Is there a way to specify this 'Cert' field anyhow? Or is this not possible for now?

Comment: This must be done outside. Btw the signing method you use is somewhat outdated. Use the one shown in the Create*Signature.java examples in the source code download.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Unfortunately I'm forced to use this method for now. I will look in other ways to set the 'Cert' field. The PDSignature still has the SUBFILTER_ADBE_X509_RSA_SHA1 option, maybe delete this in the future?

Comment: Btw you can set anything with signature.getCOSObject(COSName.getPDFName("Cert"), item);

Comment: @Bas Did Tilman's comment help you along?

Comment: Yes @mkl , TilmanHausherr did help me along, see the answer below.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for your help, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TimanHausherr mentioned, it's not possible for now to set the cert value directly in PDFBox (2.0.4). Still it is possible to include the 'Cert' entry manually using the following method:

```java
byte[] cert = ...;
PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
COSString certCosString = new COSString(cert);
signature.getCOSObject().setItem("Cert", certCosString);
```

The cert field will now be included when PDFBox signs the document with 'signature'.